# Get the value of a specific key in a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, trygetvalue

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> mydict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I have tried:

```
foreach(var value in mydict.Keys)
{
    List<string> key
    key.Add();
}
```

I believe this is not the correct way to get a specific key's value.

Comment: use `mydict[key]` to get the value for `key` (in your case `key` should be `string` and the value you'll get is `List<string>`).

Comment: thanks, I was using mydict.Keys which was not giving me the key value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. A dictionary have a key and a value. In your case, the key is a `string` and the value is a `List<string>`.

If you want get the value of a concrete key, you can use:

```
myDict.TryGetValue("TheValueToSearch", out List<string> list)
```

`TryGetValue` return `true` when the key is in the dictionary. So you can do:

```
if (myDict.TryGetValue("TheValueToSearch", out List<string> list))
{
    // Do something with your list
}
```

You can access directly to the list using `myDict["TheValueToSearch"]` but you get an exception if the key isn't in the dictionary. You can check if exists using `myDict.ContainsKey("TheValueToSearch")`.

To iterate all dictionary values:

```
foreach(var key in mydict.Keys)
{
    List<string> values = mydict[key];
    // Do something with values
}
```

Apart from that, in the concrete case of a dictionary having a string as a key, you can use an overloaded constructor if you want that key will be case insensitive:

```
new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```